# Cannot be deleted due to "Bad file name or number" although the file can be opened

Tags: windows, vbscript

```
Path = split(wscript.scriptFullName, wscript.scriptname)(0)
```

The above specifies the file path used below

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run ("""" & Path & "Document.txt""")
```

The above will open "Document.txt", but the following will not delete "Document.txt" although the path is the same.

```
 CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile ("""" & Path & "Document.txt""")
```

The error message is "Bad file name or number". 
How can I fix the error?
The file name should not be the culprit because the following will delete "Document.txt".

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile ("E:\Testing\Document.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add double quotes around filenames when passing them as argument to DeleteFile

Now you are passing the string

```
"E:\Testing\Document.txt"
```

The method `DeleteFile` expects the path without the double quotes

```
E:\Testing\Document.txt
```

Changing your code to

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile Path & "Document.txt"
```

Should suffice